# Eclipse plugin: popup menu extension for ILogEntry (CVS revisions history) not showing (objectContribution at plugin.xml)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any known problems/bugs with objectContribution (popup) to CVS History view? It's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245261/any-known-problems-bugs-with-objectcontribution-popup-to-cvs-history-view-it)

I'm migrating an old eclipse 3.0 plugin to eclipse 3.4 and the popup menu contributed to the CVS revisions history is not showing at all.
I have another popup menu contributed to another perspective (CVS repository exploring) and that's working without problems (ICVSResource).

The one not working is `org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.ILogEntry`

Here is the concrete XML fragment at plugin.xml FYI.

```
    <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.console"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.ide"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.views"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jface.text"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.editors"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.team.core"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.team.ui"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.team.cvs.core"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui"/>
   </requires>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">

   <objectContribution
         objectClass="org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.ICVSResource"
         id="cvsexplorer">
      <action
            label="Pasar Recursos a Integración 1"
            icon="pai.gif"
            tooltip="Pasa los recursos seleccionados a integración"
            class="com.xxxxx.plugins.pai.actions.HammerPAIAction"
            enablesFor="1"
            id="action1">
      </action>
   </objectContribution>   

   <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.ILogEntry"
            id="revisions">
         <action
               label="Pasar Recursos a Integración 2"
               icon="pai.gif"
               tooltip="Pasa los recursos seleccionados a integración"
               class="com.xxxxx.plugins.pai.actions.HammerPAIAction"
               enablesFor="1"
               id="action2">
         </action>
   </objectContribution>

</extension>
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

---

I'm updating this issue here: [Any known problems/bugs with objectContribution (popup) to CVS History view? It's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245261/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was resolved here: [Any known problems/bugs with objectContribution (popup) to CVS History view? It's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245261/)