# Any known problems/bugs with objectContribution (popup) to CVS History view? It's not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Do you know of any problems or reported bugs with the Eclipse CVS history not showing a contributed popup for `objectClass="org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.ILogEntry"` ?

I've a popup defined in the plugin.xml and it's not showing at all. The same popup is working without problems in Eclipse 3.0.2
Here is the popup definition at plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
   <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.ILogEntry"
            id="cvshistory">
         <action
               label="Pasar Recursos a Integración"
               icon="pai.gif"
               tooltip="Pasa los recursos seleccionados a integración"
               class="com.xxxxx.plugins.pai.actions.HammerPAIAction"
               enablesFor="1"
               id="action2">
         </action>
   </objectContribution>
</extension>
```

I've tried to change `org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.ILogEntry` to `org.eclipse.team.ccvs.core.ILogEntry` with the same result.

I'm using IBM Rational® Application Developer™ for WebSphere® Software 7.5.4 which includes Eclipse 3.4.2 (Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment, PDE, 3.4.2.R342_v20090122)

Thanks.

---

[**UPDATE 1**] It seems Eclipse 3.2 was the first version to broke my plugin popup, so I'm reading the [changes introduced](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/whatsNew/platform_isv_whatsnew.html) to try to find the problem.
**BTW, the CVS History was redesigned in this Eclipse version.**

[**UPDATE 2**] OK, I found that changing the objectClass from `org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.ILogEntry` to `org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.filehistory.CVSFileRevision` do the magic and, at less, the popup now is shown, but when It's called, it's not working :-(
I think I will need to change some code to adapt the plugin to the CVSFileRevision class.

Comment: Wow! 3.0.2 to 3.4.2 is a long road!

Comment: yes, I know, so I'm downloading all intermediate versions (3.1 - 3.2 - 3.3) trying to found when the plugin stopped working.
Anyway, the plugin has required a migration process (java packages, classpaths, etc.) and It's working fine except for that popup menu!
There is even another popup menu that is working fine, for the CVS Repository Explorer.
So strange...

Comment: so when it stopped working then?

Comment: @nanda I've tested it in Eclipse 3.0 (the version the plugin was developed for) and Eclipse 3.1 and the popup menu was working good.
In Eclipse 3.4 and 3.5 the popup menu isn't showing.

I'm going to test it in Eclipse 3.2 and 3.3 so I can found the version it stopped working. I'll update stackoverflow with the progress then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problems have gone.

It seems that since **Eclipse 3.2** the objectClass needed to contribute a popup menu to the History view is `org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.core.filehistory.CVSFileRevision` so changing it in the plugin.xml file enabled the popup again.

It needed some new code in my Action class in order to recognize that new class:

```
if (next instanceof CVSFileRevision) {
   resources.add(((CVSFileRevision)next).getCVSRemoteFile());
}
```

Because otherwise I was getting the next cryptic error everytime I invoked my action:

[alt text http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/4396/pluginerror.png](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/4396/pluginerror.png)

So, reputation should go to me for solving the question without other people help :-D